# JS Always check keydown

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyevent

I'm building a 3D FPS game with Three.js.

When I use a full auto weapon, I want it to continuously fire from the second you hold down the "f" key.

But instead JS detects the first keydown event, delays it for a second, and then detects the rest of them.

Kind of like this:

```
keydown>

"f" key detected...

(1 second delay)

"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
```

I assume you understand my point by now.

How can I always detect keydown events without a delay?

**Note** that I'm using the usual `document.addEventListener("keydown", ...)` for it.

*Preview*

https://i.imgur.com/ro1HZWQ.mp4

**Edit:** Some of you have been asking for code.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key == "f") {
    fire(1);
    // Since "!e.repeat" is not included, it will fire 1 round every time the key event is detected, and stop when the key goes up.
  }
});
```

Expected behaviour:

```
keydown>

"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
```

Actual behaviour:

```
keydown>

"f" key detected...

(1 second delay)

"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
"f" key detected...
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: 1 sec do you mean 1000 ms, what about click events did you test them ?

Comment: @WillJenkins but that's not the point... I want a solution to why the keydown event gets delayed

Comment: @andrewzachary For example, if I held down the "f" key for however long without letting go, the event would detect the first event, delay for 1 second, then detect the rest

Comment: Do you see how in the video, I do not let go of the key, it fires the first rounds, delays, then it will fire the rest. I want it to always fire soon as you hold the key down, not delay

Comment: That's entirely based on the keyboard's settings. Most of them have a "key repeat speed" and "key repeat delay" setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asume you are firing on each `keydown` event, while you should actually togge an `isFiring` variable to "on/true" on `keydown`, and toggle it to "off/false" on `keyup`:

```js
const conDiv = document.getElementById('continuous');
const onDiv = document.getElementById('onKeyDown');
let isFiring = false;

let isFiringShots = 0;
let onKeyDownShots = 0;

function render() {
  conDiv.innerHTML = `Shots using "isFiring" variable fired: ${isFiringShots}`;
  onDiv.innerHTML = `Shots using "keydown" fired: ${onKeyDownShots}`;
}

setInterval(() => {
  render();
  if (isFiring) {
    isFiringShots += 1;
  }
}, 50);

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 74) {
    onKeyDownShots += 1;
    isFiring = true;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode == 74) {
    isFiring = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<h2>Click here and press "j"</h2>

<div id="continuous">Shots using `isFiring` variable fired: 0</div>

<div id="onKeyDown">Shots using `keydown` fired: 0</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution. It works great now and has even improved performance a little

Comment: You're welcome! If your game is finished, I'd like to see the result!

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/opYoLQv